# El componente no aparece a la derecha del sidebar con React y Tailwind css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, headers, tailwind

He tenido problemas para posicionar de forma correcta el header, sidebar y el main de mi página. Ya logré que el header se mantenga en su lugar, pero he tenido problemas para que el main se mantenga a la derecha del sidebar de forma correcta. He utilizado flex para que el main se acomode a la derecha pero solo le permite aparecer en el espacio que genera la palabra "Main".
Las tecnologías que estoy utilizando son React y Tailwind CSS.

Este es mi App.jsx

```
const App = () => {
return (
<div  className="flex flex-col">
  <Header />
  <div className="flex">
    <Sidebar />
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Layout>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Dummy />} />
          <Route path="/rey" element={<Dummy2 />} />
        </Routes>
      </Layout>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
</div>
);}
```

Header.jsx

```
export const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-menu">
      <div className="w-full">
        <div className="flex flex-row items-center h-12">
          {/* Left */}
          <div className="flex items-center w-1/6 bg-menu justify-start pl-5">
            <Logo />
          </div>
          {/* Center */}
          <div className="flex items-center w-4/6 bg-menu justify-start">
            <div className="w-3/6">
              <SearchHeader />
            </div>
            <div className="w-3/6"></div>
          </div>
          {/* Right */}
          <div className="flex items-center w-1/6 bg-menu justify-end">
            <HeaderDropdown />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Sidebar.jsx

```
export default function Sidebar() {

  return (
    <div className="top-0 left-0 h-screen w-40 bg-menu shadow-lg">
      <div className="bg-white h-28 m3" />
      {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <SideBarButton
            icon={item.icon}
            text={item.title}
            selected={index == 0 ? true : false}
            key={index}
          />
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const SideBarButton = ({ icon, text, selected }) => (
  <button className={selected ? 'button-selected' : 'button'}>
    <div className="m-1">{selected ? icon.selected : icon.unselected}</div>
    <div className="">{text}</div>
  </button>
);
```

Dummy.jsx (Igual a Dummy2)

```
export default function dummy() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-200 shadow-innermain w-400">
      <h1 className="bg-red-90 text-4xl text-center">Main</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Así es como me aparece:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como debe aparecer:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda :(

Comment: ¿Por qué el `main` tiene la clase `w-400`? ¿Para qué sirve esa clase?

Comment: Es error mío, puse un 0 de mas